# The designer encountered an error while loading the table definition?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've problem with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

I inserted a "Sql Server Database", and when I try to "Add new table" after a while I get this problem

> The designer encountered an error while loading the table definition

and two errors in "Error List"

1. > The target database schema could not be retrieved. Unable to reconnect to database.
2. > Failed to obtain schema information from database
   >   (LocalDB)\v11.0.C:\USERS\SRDJAN\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\WEBSITES\WEBSITE3\APP_DATA\DATABASE.MDF.
   >   Please close any open editors for this database, check your connection to this database, and refresh the database in Server Explorer.   C:\USERS\SRDJAN\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\WEBSITES\WEBSITE3\APP_DATA\DATABASE.MDF

What can I do to get this working?

[image: Picture]

Comment: Is the .mdf still there?  Is SQL Server still running?  Did you reboot?

Comment: Database.mdf is in App_Data folder, and in Server Explorer,
Only Visual Studio and Chrome is running, 
Yes, same error...

Comment: Just a tip; In the future, please include an actual question for people to answer. Even if we understand that you want your problem resolved, it's easier to understand what you want if you include one.

Comment: I am experiencing this identical problem - were you able to get it working?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue, but it get resolved when I use "SQL Server Object Explorer" instead of "server explorer" to add new tables.

Comment: This worked for me, but it still does not explain the underlying issue.

Answer (score 6):

Please check that the login you are using to connect to the database in VS has the necessary permissions to create tables.

Answer (score 4):

Use "SQL Server Object Explorer" instead "server explorer" but close all the database connections that appear in the server explorer.

From the SQL server object explorer add the local SQL server and that's it, works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a really old issue but in case anyone else didn't have any luck with the answers above: what worked for me was simply disconnecting from the server and reconnecting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using integrated security (Windows Authentication), then make sure the db user has the "db owner" role.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Right click on Data Connection
2. Click Add Connection
3. Select your Data Source
4. Browse to the existing database file on your system (e.g. `C:\Users\pcname\Documents\databasefile.mdf`)
5. Click on Test Connection
6. If connection succeeded then problem should be solved, otherwise try it after restarting Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with visual studio 2013, because of wrong database name.

To solve it, go to Server explorer → right click on your database → Modify connection... → under "Connect to a database name:" select your correct database name.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Visual Studio fixed it for me. I’d had it open for a month or more.

Might be worth it to some people to try this simple step first before digging in deep.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem do the following steps:

1. Go to VS Tools → Options → Database Tools → Query And Views Designer.
2. Set "Cancel Long Running Query" after 240 second.
3. Delete all connections in "SQL server explorer" and "SQL Server Objects Explorer" - (this step is very important).
4. Reopen VS and recreate your connections.