# SQL on visual studio not working correctly

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using visual studio 2013 and I'm trying to open an SQL data table from the server explorer but it gives me an error which says

> the designer encountered an error while loading the table definition

I also tried opening it from the *SQL Server object explorer* but it still gives me the same error, how can I solve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610569/the-designer-encountered-an-error-while-loading-the-table-definition

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following:

- simply disconnecting from the server and reconnecting
- Verify that the database in VS has the necessary permissions to create tables
- verify database name: Go to Server explorer -> right click on your database -> Modify connection.. -> under "Connect to a database name:" select your correct database name.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use SSMS for to get to the same result: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Answer (score 0):

It may occur due to insufficient memory.You can check following link for reference.

https://farcajr.wordpress.com/2017/03/21/the-designer-encountered-an-error-while-loading-the-table-definition-solution-in-visual-studio/